# ODI-10017 on import Master repository

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

Importing Master repository XML files that were exported from SQL Server into `Oracle 11.2.0.4` using `ODI Studio 11.1.1.6` on Windows gets,

> **ODI-23049**: Error detected during Repository installation.
>
> oracle.odi.setup.RepositorySetupException: com.sunopsis.tools.core.exception.SnpsSimpleMessageException: **ODI-10017**: This import is forbidden: the text 2,000 has a different origin in the repository and in the import file.
>       at oracle.odi.setup.support.MasterRepositorySetupImpl.internalCreateMaster(MasterRepositorySetupImpl.java:152)
>   etc. ...

What does this message mean?  Any ideas how to resolve this?

The ODI studio runs with

- JDK 1.6.0_45
- Oracle 11.2.0.4 is supported with ODI 11.1.1.6

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Import master repository succeeded after changing ID from 0 to 1 (and after restoring fresh database backup)